# Weird shift when plt.fill_between in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have encountered some weird shifting of the filled area when using the `plt.fill_between()` from pythons `matplotlib.pyplot`.

The following is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

perf_range = np.linspace(0, 17, 17)

print(perf_range)

hsm_low     = [22000 for i in perf_range]
hsm_high    = [35000 for i in perf_range]

system_base_price = 3000
system_low  = 2 * system_base_price * perf_range
system_high = 0.5 * system_base_price * perf_range

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xscale('log')


plt.plot(hsm_low)
plt.plot(hsm_high)
plt.plot(system_low)
plt.plot(system_high)

plt.fill_between(perf_range, system_low, system_high, color='green', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

and I get the following plot:

[image]

First of all, as you can see, the green area is kind of shifted and does not really match the green and read line. Furthermore, I would like the green area be between the green, red and blue line. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `x` argument to `plt.plot(x,y)`.

```
plt.plot(perf_range,hsm_low)
plt.plot(perf_range,hsm_high)
plt.plot(perf_range,system_low)
plt.plot(perf_range,system_high)

plt.fill_between(perf_range, system_low, system_high, color='green', alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any hint on how to restrict the area to the blue line?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The blue line is at 22000. The red line is at 1500. It's your data and only you know about its meaning. You may use mathematics to shift them whereever you want them to be.

Comment: No I mean to border the filled area with the green, the red and the blue line. So far, it is only bordered by the green and the red line.

Comment: I see. That's a totally different question, which has an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417496/matplotlib-fill-between-multiple-lines).